# Riddle::OutOfBoundsError (searchd error (status: 1): per-query max_matches=1000 out of bounds (per-server max_matches=500))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I upgraded a rails application and I ended having this error in staging environment. It worked fine until I restart my searchd. 
I regenerated the config and re-indexed. I do have an old copy but it does not seem to work with it as well.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Riddle::OutOfBoundsError (searchd error (status: 1): per-query max_matches=1000 out of bounds (per-server max_matches=500)):
  riddle (1.5.11) lib/riddle/client.rb:682:in `request'
  riddle (1.5.11) lib/riddle/client.rb:228:in`run'
  riddle (1.5.11) lib/riddle/client.rb:347:in `query'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:58:in`method_missing'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:439:in `block (3 levels) in populate'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:403:in`block in take_client'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:16:in `block in take'
  innertube (1.0.2) lib/innertube.rb:127:in`take'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/connection.rb:13:in `take'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:401:in`take_client'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:438:in `block (2 levels) in populate'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in`block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in`instrument'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:566:in `log'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:575:in`log'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:437:in `block in populate'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:616:in`call'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:616:in `retry_on_stale_index'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:434:in`populate'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:187:in `method_missing'
  /home/kartz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484@rails3.0.6/bundler/gems/thinking-sphinx-55788f7b963a/lib/thinking_sphinx/search_methods.rb:412:in`search_count'
  app/models/community_stats.rb:27:in `gather_profile_counts'
  app/controllers/account_controller.rb:107:in`profiles'
  actionpack (3.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in`process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in`block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:477:in `block in _run__4420398368285199037__process_action__2238027022263059472__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:221:in`block in _conditional_callback_around_7795'
  vendor/plugins/clicktale/lib/astrails/clicktale/controller.rb:28:in `clicktaleize'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:220:in`_conditional_callback_around_7795'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `_run__4420398368285199037__process_action__2238027022263059472__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in`_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.0.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in`process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in`block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.0.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in`instrument'
  actionpack (3.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.0.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in`process_action'

Comment: Do you have a log which you can share here. It would be helpful to have better look into the error

Comment: I think the issue is lying in your gather_profile_counts method. Can you try adding max_matches => 250 and check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a summary for all the comments, riddle has max_matches as the argument in the code. It will be helpful to pass max_matches depending on the configurations.

Article.search 'pancakes', :max_matches => 10_000

Ref:https://pat.github.io/thinking-sphinx/advanced_config.html